# How to display progress in a loop without a clear enumerator in Python

Tags: python, loops, progress-bar

I have been going over answers related to implementation of loop progress using Progressbar2, but all of them require one to use the same iterator for the loop as for the progressbar module. My loop is as follows -

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk("some path"):
    for filename in files:
        pbar.update(i) #this adds a little symbol at each iteration
        if not filename.startswith('.'):
            assemblyfile=open(os.path.join(path,filename)).readlines()
            lineswithaccession=''
            for lin in assemblyfile:
                if lin.startswith('>'):
                    lineswithaccession=lineswithaccession+' '+lin
            for contig in animalcontiglist:
                if contig in lineswithaccession:
                        animalmapping[filename[:-3]].append(contig)
```

This loop takes a lot of time since there are multiple loops and checks within it (I have tried to simplify the code as much as possible). And the loop is iterating over a set of files in a folder. How can I use progressbar to measure progress of this loop?

Thank you!

Comment: why can't you swap in enumerate()?

Comment: @ch4rl1e97 thanks for the comment. Could you expand on that, i am not familiar with either enumerate or progressbar

Comment: Sure, wrap your list/iterable in it as such: `enumerate(os.walk("some path"))` and it will add an extra output, a counter that will go up in 1 each time. For the case of os.walk in particular you'll need to format the `for` line as such: `for i, (path, dirs, files) in enumerate(os.walk("some path")):` and you can then access those variables the same as you could before, with the bonus of knowing how many you've gotten through :)

Comment: @ch4rl1e97 thank you so much! I will try this

Comment: :) How'd it go?